# Question on the theory of variables and scope for a function on PHP

Tags: php

my question is a bit complex and concerns the possibility of using variables and their scope.

Let's start with a working case:

```
$var1 = "Lorem ipsum...";
$v2 ="var1";
echo "[" . $$v2 . "]";
```

the result of this code is:

> [Lorem ipsum...]

All this is very nice but .... and if I wanted to functionalize the thing?

I try to write the following code:

```
function test($variable){
    echo "[" . $$variable . "]";
}

$var1 = "Lorem ipsum...";
$v2 ="var1";

test($v2);
```

Obviously the "test" function does not have the scope of the variable that has the name contained in "variable", so the result is:

> Notice: Undefined variable: var1 in /var/www/test/indexB.php on line 3 []

At this point the question:

Is it possible to get the "test" function to acquire the scope of the instantiated variables up to the point of function called, obviously without necessarily shifting the definition of the function?

I know it might seem like a particular question, but how would you solve the problem?

Thank you,
Hello,
Massimo

Comment: You can achieve it using the `global` keyword, but be careful with that.. https://3v4l.org/XnTC7

Comment: Using variable-variables is rarely - if ever - a good idea, using an array is nearly always better. Also using `global` is a bad idea, better pass the values as arguments - as you can then control what variables are visible where.

Comment: I agree with @Qirel, but `echo $_GLOBALS[$variable];`